# How to add ListView to generic DetailView ? Django

Tags: python, django, templates, generics, view

Hi I'm trying to create a portfolio page where I display a list of projects beneath one of the project details.  Using generic listview I can display the list of projects.

In my project detail I can use the DetailView to show the project.  However I cannot get the list of projects to display in my project detail below the detail.

I extended the base template so the template blocks for the list and projects live in different html files. So I don't think the problems are in my template.

**views.py**

```
class ProjectView(generic.DetailView):
      template_name = 'portfolio/project_detail.html'

      def get_queryset(self):
          return Project.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
      template_name = 'portfolio/index.html'
      context_object_name = 'project_list'

      def get_queryset(self):
           return Project.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),,
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ProjectView.as_view(), name='project]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your ProjectView add this function:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProjectView , self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['projects'] = Project.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')
    return context
```

This way you can access the list of projects in your template with `{{projects}}`

Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data)

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the first item in my list to show, but I'm having trouble looping the list. My template looks like this but won't loop
    `{% for project in projects %}
        <ul class = "list" style="list-style-type:none">
        <div class = "portfolio_list">
            <div class = "project-title">
                <li>{{ projects.projecttitle }}</li>
            </div>
        </div>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}`